# Is there any way to change the color of the verticle lines when it gets active/highlited which connects the open and the close tag?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, tags, line

[image: vs code editor]
Is there any way to change the color of the verticle lines when it gets active/highlighted which connects the open and the close tag?

Comment: your question doesnt have anything to do with html and css. to change the color of that vertical line you will have to install an extension

Comment: can you suggest any of the extension